# Difficulty to join developer name and tester name in SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a `employee` table with the following columns:

```
eno 
ename 
desig
```

There is also a `project` table  and columns are:

```
pid 
pname 
devId 
tesid
```

`Employee`

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
|   Eno  | ename    | desig     |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 1001   | Ramesh   | Developer |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 1002   | Senthil  | Tester    |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| INV003 | Suresh   | Developer |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

`Project`

```
+-----+----------+-------+---------+
| PID | PName    | DevID | TesName |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+
| P01 | Project1 | 1001  | 1002    |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+
| P02 | Project2 | 1003  | 1002    |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+
```

I needed result set as like below with join:

```
+-----+----------+---------+----------+
| PID | PName    | DevName | TestName |
+-----+----------+---------+----------+
| P01 | Project1 | Ramesh  | Senthil  |
+-----+----------+---------+----------+
| P02 | Project2 | Suresh  | Senthil  |
+-----+----------+---------+----------+
```

I tried with inner join but I could only get developer name. How can i join it with the test name as well?

Comment: Can you format your question better? Also there seems to be repetitive sentences, can you fix that please?

Comment: What's your inner join statement? Why does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to join to Employee table twice. Just put an alias for each table. See below

```
Select 
    PID,
    PName, 
    dev.ename as 'DevName',
    test.ename as 'TestName'
FROM Project proj
LEFT JOIN Employee dev 
    on dev.Eno = proj.PID
LEFT JOIN Employee test
    on proj.TestName= test.Eno
```